# REST API: How to find groups with "Full Control" permission level using Id and RoleTypeKind

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, sharepoint-permissions, id, permission-levels

in a javascript file, using Rest API, I need to get groups with full control as permission level.

I call

```
_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('MyTitle')/items(23)/roleassignments?$expand=roledefinitionbindings
```

and I've noticed, calling this url on two different sites, that in the returned json the "Full Control" permission level is described in this way:

```
BasePermissions: Object { High: "2147483647", Low: "4294967295" }
​​​​​Description: "Has full control."
​​​​​Hidden: false
​​​​Id: 1073741829
​​​​​Name: "Full Control"
​​​​​Order: 1
​​​​​RoleTypeKind: 5
​​​​​"odata.editLink": "Web/RoleDefinitions(1073741829)"
​​​"odata.id": "https://pinco.sharepoint.com/teams/pallino/Pallo/_api/Web/RoleDefinitions(1073741829)"
​​​​"odata.type": "SP.RoleDefinition"
```

.
In particulary I've noticed that Id and RoleTypeKind never change in my two sites. I don't have any doubts about RoleTypeKind Enum but I wonder if ​​​​Id **1073741829** is equally valid to find all groups with "Full Control" permission level.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the ID 1073741829 represents "Full Control" permission level.

Here are some out of the box ids below:

[image]

Read this blog for more:http://buildsharepointconcepts.blogspot.com/2017/04/get-sharepoint-role-definition-ids-out.html

For RoleType enumeration:

[image: 0 none]

Reference: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/ee536725(v%3Doffice.15)